# How to wait for the child of the body?

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

[On this page](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=stackoverflow), I want my Chrome extension to wait for all the page elements to completely load. How do I do that? The first `MutationObserver` works and the second does not.

```
var waitForBody = function() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    if (document.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('body')) {
      return resolve(document.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('body'));
    }
    const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
      if (document.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('body')) {
        resolve(document.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('body'));
        observer.disconnect();
      }
    });
    observer.observe(document.documentElement);
  });
}

var waitById = function(elmId) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    if (document.getElementById(elmId)) {
      return resolve(document.getElementById(elmId));
    }
    const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
      if (document.getElementById(elmId)) {
        resolve(document.getElementById(elmId));
        observer.disconnect();
      }
    });
    observer.observe(document.body, {childList: true});
  });
}

waitForBody().then((elm) => {
    console.log('elm is ready');
    console.log(document.getElementById('xt-popover'));
  waitById('xt-popover').then((elm2) => {
    console.log('elm2 is ready');
  });
});

# elm is ready
# null
```

[image]

Comment: Possibly because the element with the id already exists when you create the MO? I'd just create both MO's immediately. There's absolutely no point waiting for content to load given the pattern you're using.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I tried `waitForBody().then((elm) => {...});` then `waitById('#xt-popover').then((elm2) => {...});` Result is the same, `#xt-popover` does not find.

Comment: Your second observer only applied to elements who's parent is `body` element. You should probably add `subtree: true` to it's options.

Comment: @vanowm `body` is the parent of `#xt-popover`. I don't need `subtree: true`.

Comment: Since you're using `document.getElementById` not `document.querySelector`, you'll need to use `waitById('xt-popover')` instead of `waitById('#xt-popover')`.

Comment: @Bergi Unfortunately, it didn't help. This code does not print anything: `waitForBody().then((elm) => {waitById('xt-popover').then((elm2) => {console.log('elm2 is ready');});});`

Comment: Your code works just [fine](https://jsfiddle.net/jph4L6e5/). Perhaps the issue is empty element added to the `body` and later `xt-popover` id assigned to it. In that case, you'll need observe attributes changes instead.

Comment: @vanowm For some reason it doesn't work on the YouTube search page when launched from content-script.